# fillna(0) does not work

Tags: python, dataframe

Hi everyone I'm new to Python and I couldn't find my answers nowhere so I'm here looking for some help.

So the background knowledge is, I have a big data frame and each time I should select a few columns for some particular research purpose. Normally I would use `df.fillna(0)` to replace all NaNs in my selected data frame with value 0, which worked perfectly fine when I selected multiple columns at a time. But when I select only one column, it pops error saying my data frame still has NaN values. I was wondering if this has anything to do with the number of column, and if someone sees this knows how to solve it.

The code that I am using is:

```
data = Demo_NY.loc[:,feature_name]
data.fillna(value = 0)
data = data.applymap(int)
```

Demo_NY here is the data frame, all entries are store in string format, which is why I have to use `data.applymap(int)` after selecting them. But it pops out error saying there's NaN, I thought I've replaced all NaN in second line.

Sorry for my poor editing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post your code so that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: I was gonna post the code but I figured it might not be helpful since I can't share the data.
Anyway, the code is:
`data = Demo_NY.loc[:,feature_name]`
`data.fillna(value = 0)`
`data = data.applymap(int)`
Here the Demo_NY is the data frame, all entries are stored in string format, which is why I have to `data.applymap(int)` after selection. But this accepts no NaN

Sorry for my poor editing, I have no idea how to make it cleaner...

Comment: I've edited your question to add this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `data.fillna(value=0, inplace=True)`

Comment: Thanks! It works, although I'm still confused why this error didn't pop before.

Comment: it's maybe because you used to do: `data = data.fillna(value=0)`

Comment: No, I've used the same chunk of code for over a week, and this is the first time I'm seeing this error.